# Git not detecting a directory

Tags: windows, git, github

I've found questions similar to this, but they didn't work in my case, so I'm posting this.

In my windows machine, I have a folder say abc and inside that a directory bin, in which all my files are present. For some reason, git does not detect any contents of the directory abc unless I move the files from bin to abc.
What should I do to detect the files when it's inside bin directory?

Comment: What is the content of your `.gitignore` file?

Comment: Here is the file https://www.dropbox.com/s/anymg6v4lpz28uq/.gitignore?dl=0

Comment: Ok, does it contain anything that you might consider relevant to your issue?

Comment: The .gitignore file was automatically generated by the application. And since many of my main files will be placed in bin, it is necessary

Comment: Your .gitignore file is relevant here. There is a line `bin` which means that all files in that folder will be ignored. Git only tracks files so, if there are no other files in the directory `abc`, git will not see any content in there.

Comment: Thank you, editing the file did the job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dennisschagt had mentioned, the .gitignore file is relevant in situations like these. Since it had been auto generated for me, I didn't notice the face that it had an entry 'bin' in it, which was the root cause of the problem. removing it solved my problem of having the flder and its contents non-detected. Thank you all for the help.